# HFT Error when signing document

Tags: adobe-acrobat

When digitally signing a document in Acrobat Reader DC, after clicking on sign and choosing a location to save the signed document, following error occurs:

> HFT Error - The file is already opened or in use by another application.

The document gets saved but when opened doesn't contain the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues seems to be caused by trying to save the signed document to a Dropbox folder.

Terminating the Dropbox client or choosing a different location solves this issue.